# mysql stored function return value charset

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, user-defined-functions

I have mysql user defined function

```
DELIMITER $$ 
    CREATE FUNCTION `myfunc`(`str` TEXT) RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

RETURN str;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

it just returns passed parameter back without any changes

My problem is that if I pass some russian or greece letters then I get back only ?????? as response

```
SELECT myfunc('ывфафывавы');
```

will return 
    ??????????

if I call 
    SELECT myfunc('sdfasfsdf');
I get 
    sdfasfsdf
as result

Can't find where the prob is , any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try declaring your parameter with `CHARSET utf8` just as you define your result.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION `myfunc`(`str` TEXT CHARSET utf8) 
    RETURNS TEXT CHARSET utf8
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    BEGIN

        RETURN str;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Without that MySQL casts your incoming parameter to your default charset.